# Javascript / Type Script: Copying Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to copy an object, but I only want certain properties from the source object i.e. none of the read-only properties.  I have tried let a = b, const b = Object.assign({}, a) etc.

Source Object is an array with the following properties: -

```
0:
accountId
customerId:
description:
image:
items: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
productTitle:
selected:false
$exists:
$key:
__proto:
```

I only want the following properties in the new object:

```
0:
items: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
productTitle:
```

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this?

Comment: `Object.assign` copies all enumerable properties to the target object. If you want to copy only a subset of them, do the assignments manually.

Comment: You cannot exclude properties with `Object.assign`. Try this: `const b = {items: a.items, productTitle: a.productTitle };`

Comment: Great Thanks - this worked this.productGridData = [];
      this.products.forEach(product => {
        this.productGridData.push({ productTitle: product.productTitle, items: product.items })
      });

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the object and then take only the parts.

```
let { item, productTitle } = object,
    newObject = { item, productTitle };
```

Comment: "destructure" -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Again, please don't answer obvious duplicates.